# CoreData InnerBand undo changes

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I've just started using [InnerBand](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/InnerBand) to access my store.

One thing I can't figure out is how to do an undo of an object. I've tried setting the UndoManager for the underlying context but this doesn't appear to work.

Has anyone had experience of this?

Thanks,
MJ